# Relational operators on a class template

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, friend

This will not work

```
template<typename T>
struct foo {
  T t;
};
bool operator==(const foo &lhs, const foo &rhs) { //error, requires template arg
  return lhs.t == rhs.t;
}
```

Is this the correct way to solve this? I want define also the operators <,>,<=,>=,!= so doing `template<typename T>` on all of them would be lengthy.

```
template<typename T>
struct foo {
  T t;
};
template<typename T>
bool operator==(const foo<T> &lhs, const foo<T> &rhs) {
  return lhs.t == rhs.t;
}
```

Comment: Make them member functions of `foo`.

Comment: @jrok ok can you make an answer out of it?

Comment: "on all of them would be lengthy" ..what do you mean by it? number of characters in code? that hardly a consideration.. c++ requires them and you need to follow the syntax.

Comment: even if you make it member function,unless you define it in-class you will have to use the `template<typename T>` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two solutions: you can define them as const member functions inside the class

```
template<typename T>
struct foo {
  T t;

  bool operator==(const foo &lhs, const foo &rhs) const { return lhs.t == rhs.t; }
  // same for the other relational operators
};
```

This works because inside the class you can use  `foo` as a shorthand for `foo<T>`.

An alternative is to define them as friend non-member functions inside the class

```
template<typename T>
class foo {
  T t;

  friend bool operator==(const foo &lhs, const foo &rhs) const { return lhs.t == rhs.t; }
  // same for the other relational operators
};
```

If you define `t` as a private member, then you actually need to make `operator==` a `friend` function in order to let it gain access. Note however, that this will have the side-effect as injecting them as non-member non-template functions in the surrounding namespace. This has some consequences for argument-dependent name lookup.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't care about implicit conversions, you can set them as member functions, so you won't have to retype it each time.

but if you have to define them as free functions, I'm afraid you don't have a choice.

Comment: When should one prefer to do these operators as members over non-members? I never quite got that.

Comment: @7cows you should make them non-members when you want to allow for implicit conversions. This has nothing to do with templates though.